# How to overwrite existing file, using github actions?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have existing file called file.txt, which contains the content "1".
I want to change the content of this file, using github actions when I git push.

I tried this yaml file but the original file does not change from "1" to "2" as I wish:
name: Changing text file

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      src_dir:
        required: false
        type: string  
        default: '.'
        description: 'Path to the source code directory.'
    
jobs:
  Overwriting existing file:
    runs-on: self-hosted 
   
    steps:
      # cloning the repo 
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          
      - name: Overwrite existing file
        run: |
          echo "2" > file.txt
```

Comment: You're just changing the contents of the file which you can confirm by the `cat file.txt` command. If you want this to take effect in the repo then you'll have to push it too. BTW, what kind of self-hosted runner are you using e.g. Linux, macOS, or Windows?